# User supposed to go signup.php when add product to cart but it never happen

Tags: php

I created a jewelry ecommerce website and user supposed to go to sign up page when user is not logged in while adding product to cart but it didn't happen as expected. Can anyone advise what's the issue?

The php code is shown below

```
<?php
    include 'includes/session.php';

    $conn = $pdo->open();

    $output = array('error'=>false);

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM cart WHERE user_id=:user_id AND product_id=:product_id");
        $stmt->execute(['user_id'=>$user['id'], 'product_id'=>$id]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if($row['numrows'] < 1){
            try{
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (user_id, product_id, quantity) VALUES (:user_id, :product_id, :quantity)");
                $stmt->execute(['user_id'=>$user['id'], 'product_id'=>$id, 'quantity'=>$quantity]);
                $output['message'] = 'Item added to cart';
                
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $output['error'] = true;
                $output['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        else{
            $output['error'] = true;
            $output['message'] = 'Product already in cart';
        }
    }
    else{
        header('location:signup.php');
    }

    $pdo->close();
    echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Comment: isset($_SESSION['user']) is set but does it empty? your code not going to else part

Comment: Sorry I dont get it, the code should go to "else" statement if it cant fetch user from $_session isn't it?

Comment: isset checks if user key is in $_SESSION , which is in $_SESSION. it didn't check if it has value or not

Comment: try print_r($_SESSION);die; and debug

Comment: do u mean putting it into else statement? I did that but nothing happen :( sry im so bad at this

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){ above this line use print_r($_SESSION); die; and check what value is coming in user key in session for those who aren't logged in and overall what array is session coming with for those who are not logged in

Comment: nothing is shown there x.x the code doesnt work when i add  print_r($_SESSION); die;  above if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

Comment: I dont know how to solve it T.T , am gonna just display "login" button in check out page when user is not logged in